# Error processing response stream. Server failed with following message:\r\nAn error occurred while processing this request

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, savechanges

When we are trying to add an attachment to SharePoint list item we are getting following error message:

"Error processing response stream. Server failed with following message:\r\nAn error occurred while processing this request."

We are using WCF Data Services in MVC to add item into SharePoint List item, after adding the item, we are adding the attachment, and it saving the attachment but with getting the error.

```
var file1 = attach.FileAppCPR;
AttachmentsItem item1 = AttachmentsItem.CreateAttachmentsItem("Promotions", promotion.Id, file1.FileName);
msdc.AddObject("Attachments", item1);
msdc.SetSaveStream(item1, file1.InputStream, true, file1.ContentType, item1.EntitySet + "|" + item1.ItemId + "|" + item1.Name);
msdc.SaveChanges();
```

Please help me determine the solution of this error.

Comment: Is there any solution?